# How to Connect XML Web Services in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can u please tell me how to connect XML Web Services  in Windows Phone 7.?

Can u Give some samples on that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If u can please clarify what u mean by XML Web services.. may be we can answer ur question..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call webservice methods in Windows Phone 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620500/how-to-call-webservice-methods-in-windows-phone-7)

Comment: I think he should've asked "SOAP Client", I guess that would be clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [code sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) on the MSDN page for WP7. (The WeatherForecast example uses webservices to retrieve data).

I would suggest have a look a that page to get started with WP7 programming.

Answer (score 1):

If u are referring REST services which return XML Data,as XML Web Services, then u just have to download the content by using **WebClient** and parse the XML what you receive in the response.