# How to call webservice methods in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

For connecting to webservices i wrote the following code.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.Webservices.asmx"));
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);

void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender,DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Web service says: " + e.Result);
    using (var reader = new StringReader(e.Result))
    {
        String str = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

by using above code  Get the string result.But i want get the result in HTMLVisulaizer then i know the what are the methods having that webservice.then i can easily access the particular method.
Please tell me how to call a web service method in  Windows phone 7?in webservice i am having 5 webmethods.how to get that and how to  call the Particular webmenthod.

Please tell me thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Connect XML Web Services in Windows Phone 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620194/how-to-connect-xml-web-services-in-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jason James

The first step:

You must add referent Services ,like Jason James has very detailed instructions .

step 2 :

You can open App.xaml.cs , in Functions Apps

```
public Apps()
{
    // Global handler for uncaught exceptions. 
            UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;

            // Show graphics profiling information while debugging.
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // Display the current frame rate counters.
                Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;

                // Show the areas of the app that are being redrawn in each frame.
                //Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableRedrawRegions = true;

                // Enable non-production analysis visualization mode, 
                // which shows areas of a page that are being GPU accelerated with a colored overlay.
                //Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableCacheVisualization = true;
             }
           // You can declare objects here that you will use
           //Examlpe: NameservicesReferent.(Function that returns services) = new NameservicesReferent.(Function that returns services)();
```

Ws_Function = new Nameservices.ServiceSoapClient();

```
}
```

step 3:

in Mainpage.xaml.cs

```
GlobalVariables.Ws_advertise.getLinkAdvertiseIndexCompleted += new EventHandler<advertise.getLinkAdvertiseIndexCompletedEventArgs>(Ws_advertise_getLinkAdvertiseIndexCompleted);
GlobalVariables.***NameWedservise***.getLinkAdvertiseIndexAsync("**parameters to be passed**");
```

step 4:

```
void Ws_advertise_getLinkAdvertiseIndexCompleted(object sender, advertise.getLinkAdvertiseIndexCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
             //function returns the results to you, the example here is an array
           string[] array = null;
           try

           {
              array = e.result;
              if(array != null)

           }
           cath(exception ex)
           {

           }
           finally
           {
             array = null;
GlobalVariables.Ws_advertise.getLinkAdvertiseIndexCompleted -= new EventHandler<advertise.getLinkAdvertiseIndexCompletedEventArgs>(Ws_advertise_getLinkAdvertiseIndexCompleted);
           }
         }
```

Answer (score 5):

@venkateswara Are you talking about obtaining a list of known WebReference methods so you know which one to call in you code? Do you not see the this of known method calls when you add the WebReference to your WP7 project? Since you will be developing the WP7 app in VS I can't see the reason you would want to do this. Even if you don't own the webservice yourself, you will need to connect to it from VS in order to add the reference to your project.

Below is the screen in VS2010 where a WebReference is added. The **Operations** are listed on the right.

[image]

Once added you can use the ObjectBrowser to understand how the methods should be called.

Please let me know if I have missed something from your question.

Comment: Hi Jasonthe same steps i did.For calling a method i didn't find that method in object explorer but i saw that method while adding reference.the method name is "Genericmethod()" but in object explorer i saw "GenericWebMethodAsync()" i did n't find my method "Genericmethod()" in the object explorer it is returning dataset .Please tell me  what i am doing wrong.

Comment: I believe that in WP7 you can only call the methods asynchronously and as such the proxy that gets generated when you add the reference creates only async calls.  That is why you only see the xxxxxAsync() methods in object browser.  Hope that helps.